# aceptar numeros y el caracter - en jquery

Tags: jquery

```
 $('input[name="test"]').bind('keydown', function(e) {
  var keyCode = (e.which) ? e.which : event.keyCode
    return !(keyCode > 31 && (keyCode < 48 || keyCode > 57));
});
```

Este codigo valida que la entrada de datos contenga solo numeros, pero necesito que acepte numeros y el caracter -

Gracias por su colaboracion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que te acepte el guion(-) el Key Code es el 189, por lo tanto validaremos que tambien tome en cuenta esa tecla:

```js
$('input[name="test"]').bind('keydown', function(e) {
  var keyCode = (e.which) ? e.which : event.keyCode
  return !(keyCode > 31 && (keyCode < 48 || keyCode > 57) && keyCode != 189);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="test" />
```

Comment: Hola @Ricardo Gracias funciona perfercto

Answer (score 1):

Compara keyCode con:
**189**, es el código del guion medio ("**slash**")
y/o con 
**109** que es el código del signo de menos ("**NumpadSubtract**")